# Cannot get custom kernel to boot - mkinitpcio does not add any modules

Tags: linux, compilation, linux-kernel, kernel-module, archlinux

**1. What I am trying to achieve:**

- Build a custom kernel so I can install and run Anbox-git from AUR on my Arch laptop. Custom kernel is needed for the package to work.

**2. What I did to achieve it:**

- Download  Arch Linux kernel v5.8.5-arch1 from [here](https://git.archlinux.org/linux.git/log/?h=v5.8.5-arch1)
- I followed the guidelines on [tradional compilation Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel/Traditional_compilation) to create the custom kernel
- Via `make nconfig` I applied the changes mentioned in the [Anbox Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Anbox) page.
- Via `make nconfig` I changed EFIVAR_FS option from "M" to "*" to resolve an error from earlier attemps.
- Via `make nconfig` under `Location: -> Device Drivers-> Multiple devices driver support (RAID and LVM) (MD [=y])-> Device mapper support (BLK_DEV_DM [=y])` I added a few more options (*) because on earlier builds mkinitpcio gave errors for missing modules for DM_CRYPT, and some more DM_ modules which I cannot easily reproduce (will do if necessary for the answer, but I hope it'll be irrelevant).

After creating the config this way I did:

- `sudo make modules_install`
- `sudo cp -v arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage /boot/vmlinuz-linux58ac`
- `sudo cp /etc/mkinitcpio.d/linux.preset /etc/mkinitcpio.d/linux58ac.preset`
- Adapted the preset file per [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel/Traditional_compilation#Installation) instructions
- `sudo mkinitcpio -p linux58ac`

**Important**: The mkinitpcio runs fine, but keeps giving me a warning:

> WARNING: No modules were added to the image. This is probably not what
> you want.

- `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

**3. Expected result:**

I am able to reboot, select the new kernel from grub menu, get the usual LVM password prompt, and launch into it without problems.

**4. Result I get:**

I can reboot and select new kernel from grub but when I select it I get a

```
Warning: /lib/modules/5.8.5-arch1/modules.devname not found, ignoring.
Starting version 246.4-1-arch
ERROR device 'dev/mapper/vg0-root' not found. Skipping fsck. 
mount /new_root: special device /dev/mapper/vg0-root does not exist.
You are being dropped into an emergy shell.
```

I checked and the `/lib/modules/5.8.5-arch1/modules.devname`does indeed exist. But I think the actual problem is that mkinitcpio doesn't load the correct modules into the custom kernel, causing it to become unbootable.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: There are two stages of booting (there are actually more, but we focus on these): 1) booting kernel and **minimal** environment (initramfs) which allows 2) to access to **/** with all user space available. I believe you got and error from first stage. This also is supported by the warning message that no modules were available when you created initramfs image.

Comment: Ok, so then, are there any specific logs I could look at to help me find the cause of it? Could it be the fact that my HD is encrypted via LVM? Can't seem to grasp why no modules would be available when creating the initramfs via mkinitpcio. As I selected the modules to be installed in the kernel via `make nconfig` and ran the mkinitpcio command with sudo.

Comment: I propose rather: download [archlinux PKGBUILD](https://github.com/archlinux/svntogit-packages/tree/packages/linux/trunk) with the config, then modify the config with the values you want to set (and modify PKGBUILD with custom package name), then build your kernel with `makepkg` and install it as a package. Did you copy System.map ? Does `depmod` on new kernel works?

Comment: @KamilCuk it's okay maybe for one time use, but in general it's wrong approach. For most of the modules one may build them outside the source tree.